# Easy way to install a .deb package without aptitude or synaptic?

Tags: software-installation

I keep trying to install programs, by simply downloading the program, and clicking on it, but I see things are not that simple. Has anyone come up with a simple way to install different programs, without having to rely on Synaptic or Aptitude?

Example: I tried to install a .deb package. Went to the site, downloaded the package, opened up the command line (after making the file executable), the errors began. First there was a dependency file that was required, then there was a public key that was needed, man can someone make this a little bit simpler for a newbie. I think a newbie spends half of his time searching google to figure out how to make things work on Linux. Someone please help make this more simple? Tanks

Comment: Install Gdebi. http://askubuntu.com/a/23739/163331

Comment: sounds like you are looking to install a specific ".deb" which program are you having a problem with? And which version are you using.

Comment: ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -f mp3 -ab 192000 -vn music.mp3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To install a .deb package, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo dpkg -i <package_name>.deb
```

If you get a dependency error, you can run `sudo apt-get install -f` to download and install dependencies, otherwise; you'll have to install dependencies on your own.

For a new user, its easier to use synaptic , Ubuntu software Center, or apt to install packages.  Take a look at [How do I install applications in Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307280/how-do-i-install-applications-in-ubuntu/307286#307286)

For more info on `dpkg`, see [dpkg Command Cheat Sheet](http://www.cyberciti.biz/howto/question/linux/dpkg-cheat-sheet.php)

Comment: What about installing other programs like .exe, is that also possible with gdebi? I know the program is for Windows, but is there a way to recompile this?

Comment: Also, what about installing from a URL?

Comment: .exe files are windows based, and can't be installed natively in Ubuntu.  The way to use .exe files in Ubuntu is by using [Wine](http://www.winehq.org/).  what do you mean installing from a UR?

Comment: I remember seeing something about useing apt-get from the browser windows

Comment: do you mean "apt-links" the "Ubuntu apps directory" gives you an apt link that will open in the software center for example https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/gdebi/ (these usually are only found there because it often confuses users, and makes it hard to download files in other browsers/systems)

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for all the super fast responses. Couldn't take reading more dead end google tutorials.

Comment: To install fro a URL you can use [bower](http://bower.io/).

Comment: ps. Went to https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/gdebi/ and without fail, I have to make a choice of which app to use to open the program. Of course I have no idea which one to use.

Comment: You need to open it with the Ubuntu Software Center, or just open software center, and install it directly from there, or use Avinash Raj's answer below to install it.

Comment: tried to install ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -f mp3 -ab 192000 -vn music.mp3

Comment: What command did you use to install?

Comment: sudo dpkg -i libavcodec-unstripped-52_0.5.9-0ubuntu0.10.04.3_i386.deb

Comment: any suggestions?

Comment: just notice that this is labled "ubuntu0.10.04" maybe that is the problem. I'm running 12.10

Comment: What are you trying to install?

Comment: video conversion program flv to mp3 sudo dpkg -i libavcodec-unstripped-52_0.5.9-0ubuntu0.10.04.3_i386.deb

Comment: Take a look at http://askubuntu.com/questions/27864/best-video-converter, and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FFmpeg

Answer (score 3):

Try to install `.deb` packages through `gdebi`,

```
 sudo gdebi filename.deb
```

Run the below command to install `gdebi`,

```
 sudo apt-get install gdebi
```

Installing the `.deb` file through `gdebi` will remove the dependency errors.

Comment: sudo apt-get install gdebi
sudo: unable to resolve host srv1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
 Returned the following error:The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gdebi : Depends: gdebi-core (= 0.8.5ubuntu1.1) but it is not going to be installed

Comment: sounds like you broke your system trying to install something else @showmemn

Comment: worked, had to run sudo apt-get install -f